# Can't make Post requests to Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, protocol-buffers

So I've looked around for an answer for this but nothing I've found even comes close to solving it.

I'm trying to set up a Post method on my Web API but no matter what I do it just gives me an internal server error.

I've tried adding [FromBody] (it's a simple type).

```
    HttpClient client {get;set;}

    public APICall()
        {
         client = new HttpClient
         {
             BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1472/api/")
          };

          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));
        }


    public void PostTimeTaken(long timeTaken)
            {
                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("Logging", timeTaken).Result;
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
```

and then my controller action looks like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody] long timeTaken)
        {
            _api.DataBuilder.NumberOfAPICalls += 1;
            _api.DataBuilder.ResponseTimes.Add(timeTaken);
        }
```

I get no error message that could actually explain what's going on, just "Internal server error"

------SOLVED-------

Just in case anyone stumbles across this looking for the same answer, the issue was I was sending the data to the server in an incorrect format, it needed to be ProtoBuf serialised first, code snippet for anyone it might help:

```
public void PostToAPI(int ThingToSend)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // serialize to stream
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, ThingToSend);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // send data via HTTP
                StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
                streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf");
                var response = client.PostAsync("Logging", streamContent);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = "http://localhost:7936";
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contentValue);
                var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await client.PostAsync("/Api/Logger/PostActionLog", content);
                string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                
            }
```

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work, no error this time but nothing happened

Comment: okay. are you posting json or string ? can i get a sample code snippet of that api post method ? Like this link [Sample Image](https://pasteboard.co/Int5cVC.png)

Comment: The controller action I posted in the thread is the full controller action, there's virtually 0 complexity to what I'm trying to do and yet it doesn't work, I'm using ProtoBuf and have tried serialising the post parameter before sending and that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert
**long** timeTaken to A model like;

```
public class TimeModel {
     public long TimeTaken {get;set;}
}


public void Post([FromBody] TimeModel time){
      // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Yeah this also just gave me an internal server error

Comment: Does your request arrive your API? do you see in debug?

Comment: Doesn't show up in debug but must be hitting the API because it's an internal error not a "not found"

Answer (score 0):

Here the code of creating a simple server

```
baseUrl = "http://localhost:1472/"; // change based on your domain setting
using (WebApp.Start<StartUp>(url: baseUrl))
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     var resp = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
}
```

Here some changes in your code

```
var requestData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>   // here 
{
       new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "Logging",timeTaken),
};

       Console.WriteLine("request data : " + requestData);
       FormUrlEncodedContent requestBody = newFormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);                
       var request = await client.PostAsync("here pass another server API", requestBody);
       var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       Console.WriteLine("link response : " + response);
```

Pls add your controller

```
[HttpPost] // OWIN - Open Web Interface for .NET

public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] long timeTaken)
{
      _api.DataBuilder.NumberOfAPICalls += 1;
      _api.DataBuilder.ResponseTimes.Add(timeTaken);
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK); //Using Post Method
}
```

Comment: Still "Internal Server Error"

Comment: This link is helpful for your question https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/token-based-authentication-using-Asp-Net-web-api-owin-and-i/

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't serialising it before sending and the API was expecting a protobuf response not a JSON